ASP Web Forms Telerik Combobox Multiselect Filtering - Highlighted text is not clickable
I have a Telerik:ComboBox with CheckBoxes set to true, and filtering set to Contains.
When if i have 4 items called "Anne" "Anders" "Steven" and "Richard", and then write "An" in the search bar, Anne and Anders will appear with "An" part highlighted in a  tag. The problem is if i press the highlighted part of the item, the "An" part, then it will not be selected. Does anyone know of a work around for this problem ?
